# Create a trigger in iterm to open an application with the matched param

Tags: node.js, debugging, iterm

I have a use case where when I run the following command on my terminal -

```
 node --debug-brk --inspect Javascript.js
```

It runs node.js in debug mode and outputs a url that can be opened in chrome for debugging —

```
➜  temp node --debug-brk --inspect Javascript.js
Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/e7aae1e7-7952-41a4-9fe1-6bead23b791d
```

I have created a trigger for `chrome\-devtools.*$` in I term and set the command to

```
open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" \0
```

Such that the URL is automatically opened in chrome, but sadly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two underlaying issues that you have to work around:

- Chrome does not recognize `chrome-devtools://...` as a valid URL when passed via a cmd line parameter and tries to open it as a file scheme link and thus fails
- Chrome does not register a URL Scheme for `chrome-devtools://` with the macOS operating system and thus you can not **`open`** it

#### iTerm Trigger:

First, register `chrome-devtools://` as a valid URL scheme. There are several ways to do this, this is just one:

- Using `LinCastor` (https://onflapp.wordpress.com/lincastor/), register `chrome-devtools` as a scheme that uses Chrome to open that scheme:

[image]

Second, add an iTerm trigger to use `open` on any `chrome\-devtools.*$` regex matches:

[image]

#### iTerm Smart Selection:

Since you have the URL scheme registered, you can also open it via a `CMD-click` in the iTerm window if you add a `Smart Selection Rule` **and** an action for that rule:

[image]

[image]

Comment: To add the url scheme you can also use duti (it is available in brew). I find it easier to share configuration between different computers as you can save duti configuration to a file.